# How do you add 1W, 1M, MTD, 1Q, 1H, 1Y, YTD Range Buttons on a Bokeh Chart

Tags: python, bokeh, candlestick-chart

I am trying to get 1W, 1M, MTD, 1Q, 1H, 1Y, YTD buttons on a Bokeh chart.

I came across a Plotly [example](https://medium.com/codex/financial-charts-and-visuals-with-plotly-in-python-843ffa9341a9) which is as follows:

```py
c_candlestick.update_xaxes(
    title_text = 'Date',
    rangeslider_visible = True,
    rangeselector = dict(
        buttons = list([
            dict(count = 1, label = '1M', step = 'month', stepmode = 'backward'),
            dict(count = 6, label = '6M', step = 'month', stepmode = 'backward'),
            dict(count = 1, label = 'YTD', step = 'year', stepmode = 'todate'),
            dict(count = 1, label = '1Y', step = 'year', stepmode = 'backward'),
            dict(step = 'all')])))
```

[image: Chart with Date Range Buttons]

I want to do the same in Bokeh in Google Colab.

---

The code I have so far is:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as  np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d, Segment, Legend
from bokeh.models.formatters import NumeralTickFormatter, DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.palettes import Category20
output_notebook()

def init_chart(name):
  # Tools Selections:
  TOOLS = "pan,xwheel_zoom,box_zoom,crosshair,undo,redo,reset,save"

  p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools=TOOLS, 
             title = name)
  p.add_layout(Legend(click_policy="hide", orientation='horizontal', spacing=20), 'below')
  p.sizing_mode = 'scale_both'

  return p

def init_price_volume_chart(p, df):
  RED = Category20[7][6]
  GREEN = Category20[5][4]

  inc = df.Close > df.Open
  dec = df.Open > df.Close
  w = 12*60*60*1000 # half day in ms

  p.x_range = Range1d(df.index[0], df.index[-1])
  p.xaxis[0].formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(months="%b %Y", days="%d %b %Y")
  p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Date'
  p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 3.1415/4
  p.xaxis.ticker.desired_num_ticks = 40

  # left y axis
  low, high  = df.Low.min(), df.High.max()
  p.y_range = Range1d(low * 0.9, high * 1.1)
  p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Price'
  p.yaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0,0.00")
  p.segment(df.index, df.High, df.index, df.Low, color=GREEN, legend_label='Candlestick')
  p.vbar(df.index[inc], w, df.Open[inc], df.Close[inc], 
        fill_color=GREEN, line_color=GREEN, legend_label='Candlestick')
  p.vbar(df.index[dec], w, df.Open[dec], df.Close[dec], 
        fill_color=RED, line_color=RED, legend_label='Candlestick')

  # right y axis
  p.extra_y_ranges.update({'two':  Range1d(0, 1.1*df.Volume.max())})
  p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name='two', axis_label='Volume' ), 'right')
  p.yaxis[1].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0a")
  p.vbar(df.index[inc], w, df.Volume[inc], [0]*inc.sum(), alpha=0.5, level='underlay', 
        fill_color=GREEN, line_color=GREEN,
        legend_label='Volume', y_range_name='two')
  p.vbar(df.index[dec], w, df.Volume[dec], [0]*dec.sum(), alpha=0.5, level='underlay', 
        fill_color=RED, line_color=RED,
        legend_label='Volume', y_range_name='two')
  
  return p
```